# Proving a bound on the curve integral of a vector field

Tags: integration, analysis, vector-analysis

I want to prove

$$ \left| \int_\Gamma F \cdot dl \right| \leq \max_{x \in \Gamma} \left \{ \left| F(x)\right| \right\} \int_\Gamma dl $$

where $F : R^n \rightarrow R^n$ is continuous, $\Gamma \in R^n$ a simple, regular curve and we let $\gamma : [a,b] \rightarrow \Gamma$ be its parametrization:

By definition (the equality),

$$ \left| \int_\Gamma F \cdot dl \right| = \left | \int_a^b F(\gamma(t)) \cdot \gamma'(t) dt \right | \leq \int_a^b \left | F(\gamma(t)) \cdot \gamma'(t) \right | dt $$

Now, I really want to write

$$ \left | F(\gamma(t)) \cdot \gamma'(t) \right | \leq \left | F(\gamma(t)) \right | \left | \gamma'(t) \right | $$

after which the result is immediate, but I'm unable to prove the above. Maybe it's the wrong way to go. (I'm thinking maybe I'll have to use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality? Can't seem to figure it out..)

Any pointers are appreciated!

Comment: Yes it follows immediately from Cauchy-Schwartz

Comment: Okay, thanks! Still can't "see" it, but I'm almost there.

Comment: Maybe it will be more obvious if you make $\gamma$ unit speed, with $\int_\Gamma d\ell = b - a$

Comment: I've got it now, hadn't fully internalized Cauchy-Schwartz. It's immediate, as you said. The rest of the proof is just replace $F(\gamma(t))$ by it's max over $t \in [a,b]$, which is a value in $R$ and doesn't depend on the integral anymore. Factor it out, and it's done.